# array won't let me print % of sums in array

Tags: java, arrays

below is my code, my situation is that im trying to get the percent array to output the % in 2 decimals, however I keep getting an error about lossy conversion from double to int, I have tried putting my array for percent as both an int and double but I am having no luck.

what do I need to do to get it to display the percent instead of 0's or the error?

```
import java.util.Scanner;   // import Scanner class
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class DiceSim
{
    public static final SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
    public static final Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);  // create scanner object called input
   // start main method
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      double[] percent = new double[13];
      int roll1 = 0;
      int roll2 = 0;


      System.out.printf("%n *******************************");
      System.out.printf("%n *** Dice Rolling Simulation ***");
      System.out.printf("%n *******************************");
      System.out.println();
      System.out.printf("%n Enter the number of rolls: ");

      int input = user.nextInt();
      System.out.println();
      int[] frequency = new int[13];

      for (int counter = 0; counter < input; counter++)
      {
          roll1 = diceRoll();
          roll2 = diceRoll();
          int total = roll1+roll2;
          ++frequency[total];
          double fraction = (100.00*(total/input));
          ++percent[fraction];
        }  
      System.out.printf("%s %12s %12s %n", " Sum", "Frequency", "Percentage" );
      for (int Sum = 2; Sum<percent.length; Sum++)
      {
      System.out.printf("%4d %12d %12d %n", Sum, frequency[Sum], percent[Sum]);
      }
      System.out.println();
   }
    public static int diceRoll()
    {
        int dice = 1 + rand.nextInt(6);
        return dice;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1st of all array index can't be double. Here:

```
++percent[fraction];
```

2nd change the %d to %f. Here:

```
 System.out.printf("%4d %12d %12d %n", Sum, frequency[Sum], percent[Sum]);
```

Comment: it seems to not be calculating the percent i got it to output it in 2 decimal as 0.00 but all of them are saying 0.00 percent

Comment: Can you update your code so we can take a look what you did? Because right now you have problem with this line: ++percent[fraction]; because your array length is 13 but fraction can be way higher than index 13. Here: int fraction = (int) (100.00*(total/input)); And after that you have logical problem on this line:  System.out.printf("%s %12s %12s %n", " Sum", "Frequency", "Percentage" );

Answer (score 0):

`%d` is for decimal. You want to use `%f` for floats and doubles. Please consult the documentation for formatting: [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Also, the reason why you're getting 0s when you use ints, is because Java truncates floats and decimals - it does not round them. Your percents are probably less than 100 percent, so they are less than 1. If it's anything between 0 and 1, it will get truncated to 0.

Update:
Your problem is because you're using a double to access an array index with

```
double fraction = (100.00*(total/input));
++percent[fraction];
```

which takes an int. So that means it would have to convert from a double which is 64 bits to an int...I don't even think that should compile, so I'm not sure how you're getting "loss of precision".

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than "it doesn't work"

Comment: it says the loss conversion from double to int under the ++percent[fraction];